# Why with additive checks on login fail user is entered into the system?

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

In laravel 9 with breeze 1.11 I need to add additive checks on field if user is admin.

In app/Http/Requests/Auth/LoginRequest.php I add lines :

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    \Log::info(varDump(Auth::user()->is_admin, ' -1 Auth::user()->is_admin::')); // I see data of logged user
    if(!Auth::user()->is_admin) {
        \Log::info(varDump(-13, 'RAISE ERROR')); // I see this log line
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('You have no admin credentials'),
        ]);
    }
    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

But anyway user is logged into dashboard.

Which method is correct for this task ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question why is someone being logged in with incorrect credentials, or why are you seeing a failed `is_admin` entry in your error log? It's not clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If this login should not be used by someone that is not an admin then you can add the check as an additional condition on the Auth::attempt method  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#specifying-additional-conditions

Comment: Only user with is_admin = true can login into the system. I try to raise error if is_admin = false - but user anyway is logged

Comment: Is docs at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#specifying-additional-conditions related to breeze auth ? It looks differently

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with manual logout method :

```
if(!Auth::user()->is_admin) {
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'email' => 'You have no admin credentials',
    ]);
}
```